# Computer settings in group policy are not applying...User settings applied easily..how?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

We have a in house domain controller (DC1.xyz.local) & child domain controller (cdc1.abc.xyz.local)...I have below mentioned problems -

1. None of the computer settings getting applied on to any of the computers.Tried lots of things on computer side.Checked network setting 'they are perfect'..wherein user settings are applied.Is it something related to forest-child domain controller issue? or am I having a faulty desktop image? or a DNS server issue? Need urgent help!!!!
2. I dont see Default domain policy in child domain controller's GPMC. Is it because it is a child domain, or someone has deleted it? If yes, what shall I do?

Answer (score 3):

I have seen the exact symptom described here, user settings applying but not computer settings, in exactly two cases:

1. The computer was in a remote office and required a VPN to connect to the enterprise network.
2. In the wireless network that required a captive-portal login to connect to the enterprise network.

In both cases, the computer wasn't able to log in to the domain-controllers before the user login. Because of that, they weren't able to pull the GPOs needed. Once the user logged into either the VPN or the captive-portal settings were able to be applied but not consistently. This hit imaged machines worst, as they frequently would get thrown on the requires-login network so wouldn't be able to cache the GPOs for application at boot. The fix was one of two things:

1. Have freshly imaged machines log in via the wired network once before sending out to wireless.
2. Poke holes in the captive portal to allow AD login w/o portal login.